# Where to download (Dutch) Postgresql Fulltext Search dictionaries

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

PostgreSQL enables me to configure what dictionaries I would like to use when preforming a fulltext search. The following types of dictionaries can be set:

- stop
- ispell
- simple
- snowball
- synonym
- thesaurus

It comes with some .stop dictionaries and example files included, if you install the .deb file through PostgreSQL's servers. Yet nothing to fancy. Are there any locations that one can get good filed dictionaries in any of these categories? I am searching for Dutch dictionaries in particular.

So far I found ispell dictionaries for many languages:
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/tree/
http://fmg-www.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/ispell-dictionaries.html

Any links to good sources?

**Update**

So far I managed to find the following:

PostgreSQL ships with Snowball and Stop dictionaries for a lot of languages (for sure Dutch, English and German), I have no clue how up-to-date they are.

To get good Ispell/Hunspell dictionaries I would refer you to the following post: ["Wrong affix file formate for flag" while loading dictionaries from LibreOffice in PostgreSQL 9.3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80759/wrong-affix-file-formate-for-flag-while-loading-dictionaries-from-libreoffice). In short quite okay once ship with Linux (Debian at least) check out the link on how to set it up.

For Thesaurus and Synonyms I am still hoping for input and my search continues. If I find something be for I hear something I will post it here.

Comment: You can use the hunspell dictionaries from the OpenOffice/LibreOffice project: http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can this be used for all types of dictionaries?

Comment: The hunspell dictionary en_us of Liberty Office contains errors and can't be loaded by PostgreSQL

Comment: I used the German dictionary from OpenOffice a while ago and that worked without problems. Maybe LibreOffice changed something in their dictionaries.

Comment: I checked the Dutch and English(US) of LibreOffice 4.3 and 3.3 both give errors. The de_de_frami.dict of libreOffice 4.3 is not UFT8. 
In the en_US I could even find a syntax error. Reporting it to LibreOffice also failed since their bug submission form doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I tried those from the OpenOffice project and the German one works without problems, but the AFFIX File for dutch seems to have problems (I get an error: "wrong affix file format for flag" when trying to use it)

Comment: and then CONTEXT:  line 604 of configuration file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/tsearch_data/dutch.affix": "SFX Na N 1" ? if so I get the same

Comment: Perhaps an related problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47772853/287948

Comment: Any luck finding synonyms dictionaries? I'm trying to configure my Postgres FTS and I cannot find any :/

Comment: oi, this is a 9 year old question ;-) If the Thesaurus libraries of Libre still give errors I wouldn't know where to turn. I checkout the project it was used for but they made their own for words that where relevant for the project's FAQ. Good luck and sorry I can't be of any help.